# Impersonating user with Core Service App and Angular client

Tags: core-service, custom-page

I want to make a Custom Page App, using Angular on the client and .Net Core on the backend (WebService)

For the user authentication, I can get the username in the JS side....but on the CoreService side, they'd have to be an impersonation user, right?

or - how would you perform the CoreService actions in the context of the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user running the thread (e.g. the IIS Application Pool user) is the only one who needs to be an impersonation user. That way you can call `Impersonate`, passing in the username, and all subsequent actions will be done as that user.

Comment: Experience shows that if you use the Network Service account it tends to work just fine.